# How to make a part of the picture grayscale in JES?

Tags: python, image, jython, partial

Hi there I'm trying to play around with my code and can't really seem to figure out how to make part of my code into a grayscale. This is my code:

```
def grayScale(picture):
      xstop=getWidth(picture)/2
      ystop=getHeight(picture)/2
      for x in range(0,xstop):
          for y in range(0,ystop):
          oldpixel= getPixel(picture,x,y)
          colour=getColor(oldpixel)
          newColor=(getRed(oldpixel),getGreen(oldpixel),getBlue(oldpixel))/3
          setColor(picture,(newColor,newColor,newColor))
      repaint(picture)


nP=makePicture(pickAFile())
show(nP)
```

Any help is appreciated, really trying hard to understand this. Thanks again for your help!

Error shown:

> grayScale(nP)
>   The error was: 'tuple' and 'int'
>
> Inappropriate argument type.
>   An attempt was made to call a function with a parameter of an invalid type. This means that you did something such as trying to pass a string to a method that is expecting an integer.
>   Please check line 8 of /Users/enochphan/Desktop/test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things giving you trouble here:

- Indenting of your code after the y for loop (I'm guessing you want all of the height to traversed).
- The new colour is just the average of your current pixels, so you need to use addition to add them before dividing by three.
- setColor() takes a pixel and a color object. The pixel you want to change is oldpixel, and the color object is created using makeColor().

Here is code with all the fixes implemented:

```
def grayScale(picture):
      xstop=getWidth(picture)/2
      ystop=getHeight(picture)/2
      for x in range(0,xstop):
          for y in range(0,ystop):
            oldpixel= getPixel(picture,x,y)
            colour=getColor(oldpixel)
            newColor = (getRed(oldpixel)+getGreen(oldpixel)+getBlue(oldpixel))/3
            setColor(oldpixel,makeColor(newColor,newColor,newColor))
      repaint(picture)
```

Answer (score 0):

**I did this instead:**

```
def greyTone():
#pict:Picture
pict=makePicture(pickAFile())
for p in getPixels(pict):
 intensity=(getRed(p)+getGreen(p)+getBlue(p))*0.1
 greyTone=makeColor(intensity+intensity+intensity)
 setColor(p,greyTone)
show(pict)
```

My professor used the r+g+b/3 variant but when I ran the code the picture was really bright, so I found this variation and it works really nice, I hope this helps :)